# Synonyms For 'Rooting For'

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

How would you say this in another way:

'I'm rooting for France tonight.'
'Oh yeah? I'm with Belgium.'

Other than supporting, of course.

Comment: [Do any of these help?](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/rooting%20for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple:

> I am **pulling** for Belgium.

**pull for** (someone or something)  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+for+(someone+or+something))

> To encourage, support, or root for someone or something; to wish the
>   best for someone or something in an endeavor or activity.

Answer (score 1):

The only other possibility which comes to my mind is **backing**.

> I'm rooting for France tonight.
>
> Oh yeah? I'm backing Belgium.

Comment: I shall be ***supporting*** England tomorrow night (and I hope on Sunday too).

Comment: @WS2 haha - but I wanted, as I specified synonyms other than 'supporting'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a different form than a verb, you can always use "I'm a fan".

> I'm a fan of Belgium

[Fan](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fan) (MW, 3rd definition)

> an enthusiastic devotee (as of a sport or a performing art) usually as a spectator

Comment: Sure - but 'I'm a fan' isn't necessarily indicative of the fact that you're rooting for that team in that particular match. It's a bit too general